# What is the limits of storage on Google Drive when using Drive API with "Service Account"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

The following URL said Storage and limits on the type of account:

https://support.google.com/a/answer/172541?hl=en

However, it does not explain using Drive API with Service account (NOT Oauth).

I am concerned about the day I get to be unable to use Drive API comes suddenly...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAIWV.png)

Comment: Drive storage is not owned by a service account. You can only give delegated access to one. The drive storage limit is determined by the type of GSuite account you have.

Comment: Is [GSuite account you have] the Google account that created this service account?
If so, the attached screen is Google Drive for that account,
-Owner is displayed as a service account.
-There is no change in the storage upper limit even if the file is uploaded with DRIVE api.
From these things, it seems that they are managed separately.